# How can I get the proper name in the output of the following SQL query?

Tags: sql

I'm trying to execute a query where the output is the name of every female that plays rugby with a male using the tables mentioned below.
This is the query I tried:

```
select distinct P1.name
from Persons P1, 
     Persons  P2, 
     SportTogether S
where P1.id = S.personA_id 
     and P2.id = S.personB_id 
     and P1.gender = 'female' 
     and P1.gender <> P2.gender and S.sport = 'rugby'
     or P1.id = S.personA_id 
     and P2.id = S.personB_id 
     and P1.gender = 'male' 
     and P1.gender <> P2.gender 
     and S.sport = 'rugby'
```

Output is:

```
+-------------------+
|       name        |
+-------------------+
| Woody allen       |
| Katharine Hepburn |
+-------------------+
```

I know that I get the proper rows using this query, but in the output, I need the female name instead of "Woody Allen". Can someone please help me out?

**SportTogether**

```
+----+------------+------------+-----------+
| id | personA_id | personB_id |   sport   |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+
| 21 |         11 |         12 | rugby     |
| 20 |         11 |         14 | badminton |
| 22 |         11 |         14 | rugby     |
| 25 |         11 |         14 | tennis    |
| 23 |         13 |         12 | rugby     |
| 19 |         14 |         11 | tennis    |
| 24 |         14 |         13 | badminton |
+----+------------+------------+-----------+
```

**Persons**

```
+----+-------------------+-----------+-----+----------+--------+
| id |       name        |  address  | age | eyeColor | gender |
+----+-------------------+-----------+-----+----------+--------+
| 11 | Woody Allen       | Amsterdam |  35 | green    | male   |
| 12 | Charlton Heston   | Rome      |  68 | green    | male   |
| 13 | Katharine Hepburn | Rome      |  87 | brown    | female |
| 14 | Rachel McAdams    | Leipzig   |  70 | blue     | female |
+----+-------------------+-----------+-----+----------+--------+
```

Comment: `SELECT CASE WHEN P1.gender = 'male' THEN p2.name ELSE p1.name END from ...`

Comment: Just swap PersonA and PersonB in the second part of your request such that P2 has ‘male’ gender not P1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this -

```
select case when P1.gender = 'male' then P2.name else P1.name end as name
from Persons P1, 
     Persons  P2, 
     SportTogether S
where P1.id = S.personA_id 
  and P2.id = S.personB_id
  and P1.gender <> P2.gender 
  and S.sport = 'rugby'
group by case when P1.gender = 'male' then P2.name else P1.name end;
```

Also note that there is no need for the OR part in your query.

Answer (score 0):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

```
select distinct pf.name
from SportTogether s join
     Persons pf
     on pf.id in (s.personA_id, s.personB_id) and
        pf.gender = 'female' join
     Persons  pm
     on pm.id in (s.personA_id, s.personB_id) and
        pm.gender = 'male'
where s.sport = 'rugby';
```

Each join is to one of the two people in the "plays together" table.  One matches on a female and the other matches on a male.  If there are two males or two females, then one of the joins will fail and that "plays together" record is not in the result set.